# Count length of string then add to cx

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have this code:

```
mov ah,9
lea dx,[100]
int 21

mov ah,0a       ; input string
lea dx,[110]
int 21

mov dl,0d       ; new line
mov ah,2
int 21
mov dl,0a
mov ah,2
int 21

mov cx,6
lea si,[112]        ; this
mov ah,2
mov dl,[si]
int 21
inc si
loop this
```

I want to make that "mov cx,6" into a variable, by counting the length of the string inputted by the user.

I have this:
e 100 'enter your name: $'
e 110 20,0,0

(P.S. I put "6" in cx because i inputted 6 characters)
(P.S.S Im only using debug.exe of 8086 assembly)

Note: I know that i could just output the string itself by adding $ on the inputted string and doing mov ah,9. But, i want it to use character output with looping.

Comment: Using `debug` is an extremely tedious way of writing assembly.  That said, what is your question?

Comment: We are on the beginning part of the lesson that's why we are to use debug. I want to make that "mov cx,6" into a variable, by counting the length of the string inputted by the user.

Comment: Do you know how to find the length of a string?  If yes, do that to the user's input and store it in some variable.  You make a variable by reserving 2 bytes somewhere in memory for them.

Comment: Actually, no. I found some programs that counts the length of the string but i cant manage to merge it with my current codes.

Comment: You should not copy other people's code.  Do you know how to find the length of a string, that is, how a program that finds the length of a string would work?

Comment: You don't need to "find" the length of the string. The length will be stored at location 111 due to the way the MSDOS input string INT 21H call works.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 reasons why this code will fail.

- You destroy the **$** character that ends the initial message.
  When you issue the commands `e 100 'enter your name: $'` and `e 110 20,0,0` in a row, the **$** will be overwritten by a zero! Better space your addresses or shorten the message.
- You keep processing only the first character `CX` times.
  Because `loop this` jumps to `lea si,[112] ; this`, the `SI` register will get reloaded with the same value each time. Put the target *this*, one line further below.

> I want to make that "mov cx,6" into a variable, by counting the length of the string inputted by the user

There's no need to count anything since DOS already gave you the length of the string. You can fetch it by reading the 2nd byte of the buffer that you provided.

```
mov     cl, [111]    ; 2nd byte contains length of inputted string
mov     ch, 0        ; Make word because LOOP uses CX, no just CL
lea     si, [112]    ; String starts at 3rd byte
mov     ah, 2        ; this
mov     dl, [si]
int     21
inc     si
loop    this
```

If you insist on not using this DOS-provided length of the string, you could process the characters until you encounter the terminating carriage return (13 or 0D in hexadecimal)).

```
mov     cx, 0        ; Reset your variable
lea     si, [112]    ; String starts at 3rd byte
jmp     that
mov     ah, 2        ; this
int     21
inc     cx           ; Your calculated length!
inc     si
mov     dl, [si]     ; that
cmp     dl, 0D       ; Terminating carriage return?
jne     this         ; Not yet
```

Here `CX` is your variable that has the length of the inputted string.